# Bootstrap and Unify can't click on submenu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, unify

I purchased Unify and I have it up on a server here:

[hidden]

When on my android I expand a menu item with a submenu but when trying to click on a submenu item the menu just contracts and nothing happens! Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Had to move back 1 version to 2.3.1 of bootstrap